# Extract ZIP into QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, zip, qbytearray

How to unzip ZIP-archive into `QByteArray` (C++ Qt)?
I tried to unzip use `QuaZip` and `QZipReader` - all of this methods needs to extract ZIP data into some file destination (must be `QString` - destination path). 
Thank`s to all, who read this question.

Comment: This is about some 3rd party libraries and not Qt but related to Qt. I doubt that is the right question here. Anyway: http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.8.6-browser/d7/df4/class_q_zip_reader.html#adc03c6db73107d9e7b729e7b64a2236b

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are actually looking for. It may be useful to show what you have already done ([mcve]).

Comment: Initially, I have a QbyteArray (not a file!) сontaining a ZIP archive. I need to expand the data and transfer it again to QByteArray (not to the file!)

Comment: Take that opensource library and add own method?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply "unzip" into a bytearray, because zip (unlike plain gz) contains multiple files and folders, and not just a data stream. How would you seperate those in a single bytearray?

What you can do, is extract each file (or a single file, if your archive only contains one) inside the archive.[`QuaZipFile`](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/classQuaZipFile.html) inherits [`QIODevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html). This means, you could simply interate over the archive and extract every file in it, and use `quaZipFile.readAll();` to get the data as bytearray. This would give you one bytearray per file inside the zip archive.

Comment: Felix, yes, you are right! I want to unzip all parts of zip file - all files which starts with \x504b0304 - local file header into qbytearray. Thank you!